# How can I remove Skype 8's icon from the menu bar?

Tags: menu-bar, skype

Skype 8 does not allow to remove its icon from the menu bar in their settings anymore. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Skype 8 is an Electron app you can modify its source code. Run this command in Terminal:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -i '' -e "s/this._tray =/\\/\\/is._tray =/" -e "s/this._trayBaseToolTip =/return;\\/\\/yBaseToolTip =/" /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar
```

It will prevent the menu bar icon from being created.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to press and hold down your <kbd>cmd</kbd> key, click the icon and with your mouse button pressed down move the cursor to some part of your screen outside of the menubar. There you can drop it (release the mouse button). It should become a cloud of dust and disappear.
I personally do not use Skype, but it works with every icon I have in my menubar except for notifications.

Comment: Nope. Skype doesn't allow this.